# Can anybody help me with a Mysql subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery

here is my query:

```
SELECT id, lastname, firstname,

( SELECT COUNT( courses.id )
FROM courses
LEFT JOIN members_courses
ON courses.id = members_courses.course_id
WHERE members_courses.member_id = members.id ) as attended_courses

FROM members

LIMIT 10;
```

It works fine, but now I need to select only rows where attended_courses = 0;

How do I do that?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HAVING keyword is used for postprocessing, similar to WHERE, which is used for preprocessing.

```
SELECT id, lastname, firstname,

( SELECT COUNT( courses.id )
FROM courses
LEFT JOIN members_courses
ON courses.id = members_courses.course_id
WHERE members_courses.member_id = members.id ) as attended_courses

FROM members
HAVING attended_courses=0
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this idea is to have subquery work as a table so you may need to bring member.id=member_courses.memeber_id outside subquery, try both ways.:

```
SELECT id, lastname, firstname,cnt 
from  ( SELECT COUNT( courses.id ) as cnt FROM courses 
        LEFT JOIN members_courses ON courses.id = members_courses.course_id
        WHERE members_courses.member_id = members.id ) attended_courses, 
members 
where cnt=0 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your query using joins

```
SELECT m.id, m.firstname, m.lastname , COUNT( courses.id ) attended_courses
FROM members m
LEFT JOIN members_courses mc ON mc.member_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN courses c ON c.id = mc.course_id
GROUP BY m.id, m.firstname, m.lastname
HAVING  attended_courses = 0
```